# How to setup SMTP authentication for a backend-frontend contact form in a Linux environment (CentOS)?

Tags: security, email, php, smtp, hosting-services

On a CentOS-Bash shared hosting environment I host a website with a simple backend-frontend contact form with the PHP `mail()` function.

Test emails can reach my Gmail account but if they do reach it at all (which is very rare), it takes much time, usually more than an hour.

---

I understood from an infrastructure developer from my hosting company that this is because:

- The emails are eventually sent from `RANDOMLY_CREATED_USER_@us153.siteground.us` which doesn't have valid DKIM, valid SPF, and SMTP authentication

The infrastructure developer suggested that to solve this problem I would open an email account in my hosting environment and refer emails to there, so then I would indeed have valid DKIM, valid SPF and SMTP authentication.

---

But say that I still want to refer emails to my Gmail account;
How to setup SMTP authentication for a backend-frontend contact form in a Linux environment (CentOS)?
Would that even be possible on a shared hosting environment (and then what about DKIM and SPF?)...

### Notes

- Another problem added upon the one described above occurred with a second form which is a bit more complex than the simple test form in the base of this session;
  The `"From" => $email` *header's email address* was my own Gmail address so an eventual sending from `RANDOMLY_CREATED_USER_@us153.siteground.us` was mistakenly grasped as *email faking* ("spoofing"), again, on top of the server mismatch described above

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `mail()` relies on the Mail Transfer Agent (MTA for short; it's an email service software like Sendmail, Postfix, Exim, OpenSMTPD...) of the underlying operating system. In your case the MTA of the web host seems to be running essentially on "factory defaults", indicating that the hoster has not expected it to actually be used for outgoing mail in this fashion.

I would recommend changing your PHP form handler to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or something similar instead of the very rudimentary `mail()`. That would allow you to specify the mail server  in your application, instead of relying on the host's default settings.

This will also allow you to use features like SMTP authentication (and its necessary companion, encryption). If the web host is shared between several users, you most likely won't have root access to it - and in that case, using something like PHPMailer might be the only way you *can* choose the mail server settings your application will use.

DKIM and SPF are relevant if you want to send mail to the world; for just forwarding mail to one single account they're overkill. By configuring your application to contact the SMTP server using port 587 or 465 (depending on exactly how TLS is going to be applied), your application gets to basically act like a mail client when sending mail, letting the SMTP server administrator to worry about DKIM and SPF. But the server administrator will require you(/your application) to authenticate before it will let you benefit from the server's DKIM and SPF... and encryption is needed because you don't want to pass your authentication credentials to the server unencrypted.

Even so, I'd recommend against using your personal Gmail account for sending emails through a web form. Get a separate account, just in case the webhost gets hacked and the mail access credentials get stolen.

Comment: Hi, I thank you for helping me with this. Just about the last passage --- I have no desire to send email from Gmail itself even from a separate account; if indeed I stay with my own Gmail and not creating an email account on the hosting provider's end, I would still use Gmail only to reply to emails, but not to sending emails.

Comment: `DKIM and SPF are relevant if you want to send mail to the world; for just forwarding mail to one single account they're overkill` As I felt, thank you !

Comment: I think one thing I miss from your answer --- is SMTP authentication always done on an MTA or sometimes on the backend language, or on both?

Comment: It's usually done between any client that wants to send email and the MTA... it's almost a requirement there if the MTA is administered according to current recommended practices. It's technically possible to do authentication between MTAs too, but that's rare: perhaps like between two allied organizations that want extra security on email between them but don't quite want to set up an inter-organization VPN or similar yet. It would not be reasonable for every mail server administrator to get authentication credentials for every other mail server in the world.